# select and move the contents to another file

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk

I have a file with the below contents. All I need to do is filter the **ALTER** script that has **UNIQUE** keyword in it and move it to a different file. I tried using `sed -n '/ALTER TABLE/,/UNIQUE("ID");/p' file`.  But it didn't work.

```
ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACL_ENTRY
            ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.FK5111A
            FOREIGN KEY( ACL_OID )
            REFERENCES RELEASE.ACL ( OID )
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            --ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
    ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACTION_DESC
            ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.UN2160A
            UNIQUE( ID_MASK ) ;
    ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACTION_DESC
            ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.UN2160B
            UNIQUE( NAME ) ;
    ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACTION_DESC_LOD
            ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.FK2170
            FOREIGN KEY( ACTION_DESC_OID )
            REFERENCES RELEASE.ACTION_DESC ( OID )
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            --ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
    ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACTION_SET
            ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.UN2120A
            UNIQUE( "ID" ) ;
    ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACTION_SET
            ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.UN2120B
            UNIQUE( NAME ) ;
    ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACTION_SET_LOD
            ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.FK2150A
            FOREIGN KEY( ACTION_SET_OID )
            REFERENCES RELEASE.ACTION_SET ( OID )
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            --ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
    ALTER TABLE RELEASE.APP_DESC
            ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.FK20A
            FOREIGN KEY( WEB_MOD_OID )
            REFERENCES RELEASE.WEB_MOD ( OID )
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            --ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
    ALTER TABLE RELEASE.APP_DESC
            ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.CC20B
            CHECK( ( WEB_MOD_OID IS NOT NULL ) AND ( WEB_MOD_SL IS NULL )  ) ;
```

The output should be like the below contents in a different file.

```
ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACTION_DESC
                ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.UN2160A
                UNIQUE( ID_MASK ) ;
        ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACTION_DESC
                ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.UN2160B
                UNIQUE( NAME ) ;
ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACTION_SET
                ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.UN2120A
                UNIQUE( "ID" ) ;
        ALTER TABLE RELEASE.ACTION_SET
                ADD CONSTRAINT RELEASE.UN2120B
                UNIQUE( NAME ) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat inputfile | tr '\n' '@' | sed -e 's/;/;\n/g' | grep UNIQUE | tr '@' '\n'
```

Comment: Useless use of Cat anyway

Comment: Instead additional `grep` just add to `sed` : `-e '/UNIQUE/!d'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `sed` only

```
sed ':1;/ALTER/N;/;/!b1;/UNIQUE/!d' inputfile > outputfile
```

or same with pattern space use

```
sed 'H;/ALTER/h;/;/x;/UNIQUE/!d' inputfile > outputfile
```

Or you can use `awk` by same style:

```
awk 'b{b=b "\n" $0}/ALTER/{b=$0}/;/{if(b~/UNIQUE/)print b;b=""}' inputfile
```